# На локальной машине нет прав на редактирование файлов, которые создаются в докер контейнере

Tags: laravel, docker

Есть контейнер `workspace` (laradock - специальный под laravel), я захожу внутрь под рутом командой:

```
docker-compose exec -w /var/www workspace bash
```

и с помощью специальной команды создаб файл, например:

```
php artisan make:model TestModel
```

Он естественно создаётся вот с такими правами:

> -rw-r--r-- root root

И ествественно в PhpStorm у меня нет прав на его редактирование.

Что сделать, чтобы на моём локальном хосте я имел право редактировать файлы, который я создаю внутри контейнера?

Я могу сделать: `chmod 777` на этот файл, и тогда будут права, но так нужно делать каждый раз после каждого создания файла.

В `laradock` в .env файле в настройках у меня стоит `WORKSPACE_PUID=1000` и `WORKSPACE_PGID=1000`. Мой пользователь на локальном хосте имеет `uid=1000(andrey) gid=1000(andrey) groups=1000(andrey)`. Почему оно не срабатывает, и на локальной машине у меня нет прав на файлы, которые я создаю с помщью

```
php artisan make ...
```

Comment: У меня такое ощущение, что вы изначально что-то не так делаете, и из-за этого у вас проблемы. Смущает. что вы руками создаете файлы в контейнере. Зачем?

Я бы на вашем месте смонтировал  volume и кидал файлы уже туда. Тогда и проблемы с permission не возникнет, и не придется залезать в контейнер.

Comment: @instahipsta282 у меня вот есть nfs шара. я её замоунтил и могу там файлы писать, а локально туда зайти не могу. похоже такой же еффект)

Comment: Внутри контейнера установлен php и т.д, поэтому файлы создаются в контейнере. Если Вы знакомы с laravel, вы поймёте, что на локальной машине ты не выполнишь команду php artisan...

Comment: @instahipsta282 не создает руками файлы в контейнере, а запускает консольные комманды фреймворка, которые в том числе могут создавать файлы, который создаются с владельцем root.

Comment: https://vsupalov.com/docker-shared-permissions/